# How can I access the S3 bucket from internet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

At first, I make the S3 bucket with this script.

```
const out_bk = new s3.Bucket(this, 'out-bk', { // image-resize用のbucket
  bucketName: s3_out_name,
  removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
  autoDeleteObjects: true,
  cors: [{
      allowedMethods: [
        s3.HttpMethods.GET,
        s3.HttpMethods.POST,
        s3.HttpMethods.PUT,
        s3.HttpMethods.DELETE,
        s3.HttpMethods.HEAD,
      ],
      allowedHeaders: ["*"],
      allowedOrigins: ["*"],
      exposedHeaders: ["ETag"],
      maxAge: 3000
    }]
});

const s3_out_name = "s3-my-out-name"

const out_bk = new s3.Bucket(this, 'cdk-st-out-bk', { 
  bucketName: s3_out_name,
  removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
  autoDeleteObjects: true,
  cors: [{
      allowedMethods: [
        s3.HttpMethods.GET,
        s3.HttpMethods.POST,
        s3.HttpMethods.PUT,
        s3.HttpMethods.DELETE,
        s3.HttpMethods.HEAD,
      ],
      allowedHeaders: ["*"],
      allowedOrigins: ["*"],
      exposedHeaders: ["ETag"],
      maxAge: 3000
    }]
});

const cfnAccessPoint = new s3.CfnAccessPoint(this, 'MyCfnAccessPoint', {
  bucket: s3_out_name,

  name: 's3-access-point',
  publicAccessBlockConfiguration: {
    blockPublicAcls: false,
    blockPublicPolicy: false,
    ignorePublicAcls: false,
    restrictPublicBuckets: false,
  },
});
```

then S3 and Access point are successfully created.

I open the aws console -> S3 -> access point-> item

There is a object URL like this,

```
https://s3-access-point-69853XXXXXX.s3-accesspoint.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/1040
```

When access here from the browser .

There appares this error, It's something related with authorization.

I want to access this from browser without authorization.

How can I fix this??

```
<Error>
<script/>
<Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
<Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use Signature Version 4.</Message>
<RequestId>YVMHMBJP2D4WDJAK</RequestId>
<HostId>yLesp53LUmB7/rMHkZMAwcMej37WRQOKnbWI4vwhh3xCKY1t60eDd1YiJ+4xRAw3kYWjlI1Csnw=</HostId>
</Error>
```

---

I am trying to access without `Access Point`

My `block public access` is `off`.

Give everyone the privilidge for read ,list on ACL.

then accessing object URL by browser

but still comes error

```
<Error>
<script/>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>Y6DPF5RWZ59DTQJD</RequestId>
<HostId>9pXKB5EDTmE6t9AJvwyTQHtyCMokeETw9yR+BFF4JdfDZ0NbfMf3TX1+VzrrJlfULBQOUtaTNM8=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: Why are you creating and using an S3 Access Point?

Comment: I want to let the user access my img file from browser.

Comment: Yes, but why did you specifically create an Access Point? They are not required for normal S3 usage. If you want to permit public access to objects in an S3 bucket, you would use a **Bucket Policy**, not an **Access Point**.

Comment: mmmm I might misunderstand. Can I access the images without `Access Point`? like Gallary in  blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects in Amazon S3 are private by default.

If you want to make an object accessible without the user needing to authenticate, then the easiest method is to **add a Bucket Policy** to the bucket.

Here is an example from [Bucket policy examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2) that makes an entire bucket public:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Note:** Before adding a bucket policy, you will need to go to the bucket's **Permissions** and turn Off **S3 Block Public Access**.

If you do not want to make the entire bucket public, you can make specific objects public by using the **Make Public** option in the S3 management console, or by uploading the file with `--acl public-read`. Using an ACL will *also* require S3 Block Public Access to be deactivated.

Either way, the object will then be accessible via an 'anonymous' URL, such as:

```
https://BUCKETNAME.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/foo.jpg
```

**An S3 Access Point is *not* required** to grant access to objects. It is used to control security when accessing S3 objects from a VPC.

Comment: THank you very much , your help me so much. Basic practice is off the ACL and use Bucket Policy. Maybe I need to learn`An S3 Access Point`  later on , but for now, it's not necessary.